# Ubuntu linux display is weird

Tags: linux, gnome

I have installed both Fedora and Ubuntu with Gnome Desktops and it displays the information an inch to the left, this problem may have to do with the fact that the display comes up as unknown.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably fix it in the monitor settings. On your monitor, there should be a button to get into the monitor configuration. From there you might be able to do screen adjustments. Some monitors have an "Auto" button which auto adjusts the screen to fit.

If this does not work, we need more information. Is it an LCD or CRT monitor? What is the make and model of the monitor? What is the current screen resolution that you have set?